# React counter hook doesn't increment

Tags: reactjs

When I click button which run function `login` first time hooks(state) `logged` has value `0` . I wish it had value `1`

```
const [logged, setLogged] = React.useState(0);
const login = () => {
   if (tempLogin.login === "Login" && tempLogin.password == "Haslo") {
    setLogged(logged => logged + 1);
     console.log(logged);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're updating it right! Just logging in the wrong place, remember, hooks values gets updated on the next `render` and you're calling `console.log` inside `login` 
by the time login gets executed `logged` isn't updated yet

```
const Component = () =>{

    const [logged, setLogged] = React.useState(0);

    const login = () => {
         if (tempLogin.login === "Login" && tempLogin.password == "Haslo") {
             setLogged(logged => logged + 1);
     }
     //Component's body
     console.log(logged)  // 0, 1
     return <div>{logged}</div>
 }
```

Comment: I don't have idea where I should check logged value

Comment: I've updated with an example

Comment: Please also the below comment from Hamza El Aoutar about the `useEffect` dependency, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

`setLogged` is asynchronous and doesn't update the state immediately, instead you will see the updated state in the next render.

You can use `useEffect` (which tells React that your component needs to do something after render) to see the new value of `logged`:

```
const [logged, setLogged] = React.useState(0);
const login = () => {
  if (tempLogin.login === "Login" && tempLogin.password == "Haslo") {
    setLogged(logged => logged + 1);
    console.log(logged);
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(logged);
}, [logged])
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help:

```
const [logged, setLogged] = React.useState(0); const login = () => {   
if (tempLogin.login === "Login" && tempLogin.password == "Haslo") {
           setLogged(logged + 1);
           console.log(logged);  
     }
```